# How to eject disk via the commandline

Tags: windows-vista, command-line-interface, mac

Ok - i'm attempting to install Vista Business Edition on a MBP using the multi-disk installers from MSDN.

All's well until the installer demands disk 2 - the Eject key doesn't work without the mac drivers.

I know you can press shift-f10 to access the command line, is there a command to eject the cd?

Thanks,

Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nircmd utility. Check out [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-eject-the-cddvd-drive/).
You should add this tool to Vista installation using [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/), then burn a modified Vista DVD, then install happily.